# ROS Theoretical Question - How does work properly a node

Tags: ros, python

I'm new at ROS and I'm trying to figure out how does the node works with a pyton/C++ code. I have two codes for the same situation:

**Use a Xbox Controller to move the turtle in turtlesim**

FIRST - Using class python and a while as a main:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy

# DEFINING CLASS
class pubSub:
    def __init__(self):
        # DEFINE VARIABLE TO KEEP LAST VALUE
        rospy.init_node('c2t')
        self.twt = Twist()
        self.hold = Twist()

    def callback_function(self,joyData):
        self.twt.linear.x = 4*joyData.axes[1]
        self.twt.angular.z = 4*joyData.axes[0]
        self.hold = self.twt

    def assuming_cont(self):
        pub = rospy.Publisher('turtle1/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
        rospy.Subscriber("joy", Joy, self.callback_function, queue_size=10)
        pub.publish(self.twt)

ps = pubSub()
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    ps.assuming_cont()
```

SECOND - Using global variables and a `if __name__  == '__main__'` with `rospy.spin()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist 
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy 

# FUNCTION - GET JOY VALUES TRANSFORM TO TURTLE MOVE
def joy_to_twist_transform(jData):
    twt = Twist()
    twt.linear.x = 5*jData.axes[1]
    twt.angular.z = 4*jData.axes[0]
    pub.publish(twt)

# FUNCTION - START PROCESS
def process():
    global pub
    pub = rospy.Publisher('turtle1/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
    sub = rospy.Subscriber("joy", Joy, joy_to_twist_transform, queue_size=1)
    rospy.init_node('control_2turtle')
    rospy.spin()

# MAIN
if __name__  == '__main__':
    try:
        process()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

My questions are more theoretical:

1 - What I understand about how a node works is: he run the code in a loop until is shutdown. But this does not answer Why can I still save the last value published in a topic (in my head, if I run my code in a loop I start from the beginning everytime)

2 - Why is necessary to keep creating a `rospy.Publisher` and `rospy.Subscriber` in every loop? it is possible to create those guy one time only?(for example using them into **init** function in the seconde example)

3 - What is the difference between`while not rospy.is_shutdown():` and `if __name__  == '__main__'` with `rospy.spin()`?

4 - What is `rospy.spin()`? in any documentation says that keeps your node running, but the way I see he stuck the code in that line and keep there only.

If any could give any recommendation to read about those problems I would thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I made this question in ROS Answers and I made the answer (I got some experience by now): [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/319242/ros-theoretical-question-how-does-work-properly-a-node/)

Answer (score 2):

`if __name__  == '__main__':` doesn't matter at here (in the second code), also you could run your code without it like here:

## Second code:

```
.
.
.
# MAIN
try:
    process()
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    pass
```

i.e. when you don't want your code to run when it imported in another python code, you should use `if __name__  == '__main__':`

[More information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

---

The main difference between First code and Second code is that the Second code used the `rospy.spin()` method which is a built-in ROS loop that triggers the `publisher` and `subscriber` in another thread, so you wouldn't need to an inner `while` in your code like the First example.

[Relevant Question.](https://answers.ros.org/question/252545/interrupting-rospyspin-or-writing-a-custom-loop-that-does-the-equivalent/)